# Macosx button not appearing in child window

Tags: python, tkinter

My first post, so I apologize as I learn to use this. Also, I am sure my code is very jumbled and rudimentary, but I am not here to get someone to re-write my code. I have a question about how a widget is behaving and an error code I am getting.

I currently have  two frames in a mainWindow, and when you click a button labeled "New", a small window (newWindow) pops up that has a registration form, and a button labeled "Register" to write the form data to a .txt file.

The problem I am having is that if I do not define where the button should go, it appears in the mainWindow. If I specify for it to appear in the newWindow, it does not appear and throws me the following error:

> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/**init**.py",
> line 1507, in nametowidget
> w = w.children[n] KeyError: '!button2'

Here is my code (get ready for a mess!):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import strftime 
from tkmacosx import SFrame, Button
import tkinter as tk

mainWindow = Tk()

mainWindow.title('BATCO Main')

def createWindow():
    #When createWindow() is called, the following code is executed, starting with creating the window object itself, which is set to the Tk() widget caller
    newWindow = Tk()

    # Add title of window
    newWindow.title('Patron Entry')

    # Set from and geometry of the Button (widthxheight+XPOS+YPOS)
    newWindow.geometry('500x350+100+200')

    # THIS PART CREATES AND APPENDS THE FILE FOR STORING NAMES:
    def saveInfo():
        # Defines Variables(3) for the "get" Method that will take from the StringVar Variables(2) above: 
        fname_info = fname.get()
        mname_info = mname.get()
        lname_info = lname.get()
        suffix_info = suffix.get()
        addr1_info = addr1.get()
        addr2_info = addr2.get()
        city_info = city.get()
        state_info = state.get()
        zipcode_info = zipcode.get()
        print(fname_info, mname_info, lname_info, suffix_info, addr1_info, addr2_info, city_info, state_info, zipcode_info)

        # This starts by opening the file 'patrons.txt' and assigns it to the file Variable. It uses the Arg 'a' which stands for Append, so it will add to the file.
        file = open('patrons.txt', 'a')
        
        # Once the file is open, write to it using the write method on the Variable file. The Write method accepts one Arg, so I have to use the + Operator to Concatenate text.
        file.write (fname_info + ',')
        file.write (mname_info + ',') 
        file.write (lname_info + ',')
        file.write (suffix_info + ',')
        file.write (addr1_info + ',')
        file.write (addr2_info + ',')
        file.write (city_info + ',')
        file.write (state_info + ',')
        file.write (zipcode_info + ';\n')
        file.close ()
        print (fname_info, 'has been registered')

        # Clears the fields in the form
        fname_entry.delete(0, END)
        mname_entry.delete(0, END)
        lname_entry.delete(0, END)
        suffix_entry.delete(0, END)
        addr1_entry.delete(0, END)
        addr2_entry.delete(0, END)
        city_entry.delete(0, END)
        state_entry.delete(0, END)
        zipcode_entry.delete(0, END)

        # This code closes the window after entry
        newWindow.destroy()
   
    # End of saveInfo function   
    
    # Creating basic text that is formatted to be a header at the top of the window
    lbl = Label(newWindow, text = 'Create Record', bg = 'light gray', fg = 'gray', width = '50', font = ('Arial', 17))
    lbl.place(x=0, y=0)

    # Defining Variables(1) for the text box labels:
    fname_text = Label(newWindow, text = 'First Name', fg = 'gray', font = ('Arial', 12))
    mname_text = Label(newWindow, text = 'Middle name', fg = 'gray', font = ('Arial', 12))
    lname_text = Label(newWindow, text = 'Last Name', fg = 'gray', font = ('Arial', 12))
    suffix_text = Label(newWindow, text = 'Suffix', fg = 'gray', font = ('Arial', 12))
    addr1_text = Label(newWindow, text = 'Address 1', fg = 'gray', font = ('Arial', 12))
    addr2_text = Label(newWindow, text = 'Address 2', fg = 'gray', font = ('Arial', 12))
    city_text = Label(newWindow, text = 'City', fg = 'gray', font = ('Arial', 12))
    state_text = Label(newWindow, text = 'State', fg = 'gray', font = ('Arial', 12))
    zip_text = Label(newWindow, text = 'Zip', fg = 'gray', font = ('Arial', 12))

    # Placing text box labels:
    fname_text.place(x = 15, y = 50)
    mname_text.place(x = 155, y = 50)
    lname_text.place(x = 295, y = 50)
    suffix_text.place(x = 435, y = 50)
    addr1_text.place(x = 15, y = 100)
    addr2_text.place(x = 15, y = 150)
    city_text.place(x = 15, y = 200)
    state_text.place(x = 318, y = 200)
    zip_text.place(x = 367, y = 200)

    # Defining and formatting Variables(2) for the data entered INTO the Entry boxes:
    fname = StringVar()
    mname = StringVar()
    lname = StringVar()
    suffix = StringVar()
    addr1 = StringVar()
    addr2 = StringVar()
    city = StringVar()
    state = StringVar()
    zipcode = StringVar()

    # Defining the Variables(3) for the Entry boxes:
    fname_entry = Entry(newWindow, textvariable = fname, width = 14)
    mname_entry = Entry(newWindow, textvariable = mname, width = 14)
    lname_entry = Entry(newWindow, textvariable = lname, width = 14)
    suffix_entry = Entry(newWindow, textvariable = suffix, width = 5)
    addr1_entry = Entry(newWindow, textvariable = addr1, width = 51)
    addr2_entry = Entry(newWindow, textvariable = addr2, width = 51)
    city_entry = Entry(newWindow, textvariable = city, width = 32)
    state_entry = Entry(newWindow, textvariable = state, width = 3)
    zipcode_entry = Entry(newWindow, textvariable = zipcode, width = 13)

    `enter code here`# Placing the Entry boxes:
    fname_entry.place(x=15, y = 69)
    mname_entry.place(x=155, y = 69)
    lname_entry.place(x=295, y = 69)
    suffix_entry.place(x=435, y = 69)
    addr1_entry.place(x=15, y = 119)
    addr2_entry.place(x=15, y = 169)
    city_entry.place(x=15, y = 219)
    state_entry.place(x=318, y = 219)
    zipcode_entry.place(x=360, y = 219)

    # Creates a Button and assigns it to the Variable: register. It is a gray, borderless button that when clicked, calls the saveInfo function.
    register = Button(text = "REGISTER", bordercolor = 'gray', padx = 10, pady = 5, background='#BDBDBD', borderless = 'true', relief = 'groove', command  =  saveInfo)
      
    # Places the Button
    register.place (in_=newWindow, x = 200, y = 275)
    
    newWindow.mainloop()

# End of createWindow function

style1 = ttk.Style()
style2 = ttk.Style()
style3 = ttk.Style()

style1.configure('topFrame.TFrame', background='green', borderwidth=4, relief='raised')
style2.configure('bottomFrame.TFrame', background = 'blue', borderwidth=6, relief = 'raised')
style3.configure('SrchLabel.TLabel')

eFrame = ttk.Frame(mainWindow, width=1060, height=200, style='topFrame.TFrame').grid()
rFrame = ttk.Frame(mainWindow, width=1060, height=600, style='bottomFrame.TFrame').grid()

# eFrame: Title text shown before the search terms entry box
srchFrame = ttk.Label(mainWindow, style = 'SrchLabel.TLabel', text = 'Patron Search')
srchFrame.place (x='30', y='40')

# eFrame:  Search terms entry box
srchVar = StringVar()
srchEntry = tk.Entry(eFrame, bd = '1', width = '35')
srchEntry.place (x='130', y='37')

# eFrame: Button to execute Search
srchButton = Button(eFrame, text = 'Search', height = 30, width = 60, bd = '1')
srchButton.place(x = '470', y = '35')

# eFrame: Button to create New Record
newButton = Button(eFrame, text = 'New', height = 30, width = 60, bd = '1', command = createWindow)
newButton.place(x = '550', y = '35')

# rFrame: TAB Window Frame = from ttk Notebook
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(rFrame, width = 995, height = 528, style = 'rTabs.TNotebook')

# rFrame: TAB Elements
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tab1=Frame(tabControl, background="#ffffff")
tab1.pack()

tab2=Frame(tabControl, background="#ffffff")
tab2.pack()

tab3=Frame(tabControl, background="#ffffff")
tab3.pack()

# rFrame: TAB Titles and Window placement
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Patron') 
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Orders')
tabControl.add(tab3, text = 'Donations')
tabControl.place(x='5', y='205')

# TAB 1 Content
ttk.Label(tab1, text ='Patron Data').grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 30, pady = 30)

# TAB 2 Content
ttk.Label(tab2, text ='Order History and Info').grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 30, pady = 30)

# TAB 3 Content
ttk.Label(tab3, text ='Donation Info').grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 30, pady = 30)

# mainWindow: MENUBAR 
menubar = Menu(mainWindow)

# mainWindow: Filemenu
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 1) 
menubar.add_cascade(label ='File', menu = file) 
file.add_command(label ='New File', command = None) 
file.add_command(label ='Open...', command = None) 
file.add_command(label ='Save', command = None) 
file.add_separator() 
file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = mainWindow.destroy) 

# mainWindow: Editmenu 
edit = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 1) 
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Edit', menu = edit) 
edit.add_command(label ='Cut', command = None) 
edit.add_command(label ='Copy', command = None) 
edit.add_command(label ='Paste', command = None) 
edit.add_command(label ='Select All', command = None) 
edit.add_separator()
edit.add_command(label ='Find...', command = None) 
edit.add_command(label ='Find again', command = None)

# mainWindow: Helpmenu
help_ = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 1)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Help', menu = help_)
help_.add_command(label ='Tk Help', command = None)
help_.add_command(label ='Demo', command = None)
help_.add_separator()
help_.add_command(label ='About Tk', command = None)
mainWindow.config(menu = menubar)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Again, I am not looking for advice on how to write better code, as I am just learning (2 weeks in). However any help you can provide in letting me know what I am doing wrong and where I can find an answer would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about a button on a new window, we only need the new window, the button, and maybe one more button. We don't need all of the other widgets which are unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: I stopped looking once I saw two calls to `Tk()` - that's pretty much guaranteed to cause problems.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: Thank you @BryanOakley for the advice. I will do that next time.

Comment: @jasonharper that was it! I missed this in the documentation, so I did not know to use this widget. This works perfect!